# Slide in/out toggle for jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to create a slide out div using jQuery. When the picture is hovered over, a div should slide out, partially covering the photo (with info in it).

I've put together the Javascript but I can't seem to get it working.

The info is `display:none` but should show when the image is hovered over (should slide out from the right)

http://jsfiddle.net/aHRzv/

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
$("#snoodLink").hover(
    function() {
        $('#snoodInfo').animate({
            left: 0,
            right: 0
        }, 500);
    }, function() {
        $('#snoodInfo').animate({
            left: '-100%',
            right: '100%'
        }, 500);
    });​
```

Which uses the following CSS:

```
.product {
    /* ensures the positioned text element isn't
       visible before sliding in/after sliding out */
    overflow: hidden;
}
#snoodInfo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    right: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aHRzv/8/).

Incidentally, this could be done with CSS (with graceful degradation for older IE):

```
.product {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* following just center the image/element
       absolutely not necessary */
    width: 50%;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.product img {
    width: 100%;
}
/* this is the #snoodInfo element, given a class
   insead of id, to make it more generic */
.info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    right: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* to enforce the fade-in/fade-out */
    color: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    /* trying to cover as many browsers
       as possible, omitting early/old IE
       but filters could (probably) be used */
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s linear;
    transition: all 1.5s linear;
}

.product:hover .info {
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(215,50,50,0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s linear;
    transition: all 1.5s linear;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aHRzv/9/).

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to implement this on my site but although I'm using the same code as the JS Fiddle it doesn't seem to work, not sure what is conflicting with it? I've added it to the first image on the page www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/shop.html

Comment: The error console reports: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL*. This is, probably, down to the invisible/zero-width-characters that JS Fiddle (seems to) use for formatting purposes. The easiest thing to do is delete *all* white-space from the pasted code and then try again (sometimes it's also required to delete each visible character from before/after white-space and re-enter them). Actually, forget that, for a short snippet, like that, just type it in by hand without copying/pasting. Hopefully it should then work!

Comment: I've re-written the code out but it still doesn't seem to be working. I've updated the link. Interesting quirk though.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is! ...it's *also* one I (semi-frequently) swear at (or *because of*)...I'll take a look. =)

Comment: Oh, and further: take a look at some of these answers turned up via Google: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+find+remove+illegal+characters+from+JS+Fiddle+paste it's a common, common problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll revisit this in the morning!

Comment: I do like the CSS version. How can I go about adjusting the speed of the slide in? Just adjust 1.5 down to 1 or something similar?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18129/discussion-between-david-thomas-and-francesca)